# Trying to get Email.send() to work On Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, smtp, gmail

I tried reading the documentation and following tutorials online, but nothing seems to be working. I am trying to send an email with data collected from a contact form to my own gmail account. I am using Meteor. Here is my code so far: (Note: already did 'meteor add email' & tried using 'MAIL_URL="smtp://#:#@smtp.gmail.com:465" meteor' in terminal with and without the meteor startup function -- really not sure what I'm doing wrong here)

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.home.events({
    'form submit' : function(e,t){
      var to  = t.find("#contact-email").value,
          subject = t.find("#contact-name").value,
          text = t.find("#contact-message").value;
      Meteor.apply('sendEmail', [to, subject, text]);
    }
  });
}

if(Meteor.isServer){

  Meteor.startup(function () {
  smtp = {
    username: '#',   
    password: '#',   
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',  
    port: 465
  }

  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
});


  Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function(to, subject, text){

      Email.send({
        from: "#",
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        text: text
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I have this code working with an HTML form in a source/views/home folder (HTML is in Home.html, javascript is in Home.js). Let me know if you need any additional code/information for this problem. Thanks so much!! :D

Comment: I replaced all personally identifying information with #'s (except for #id's, of course)

Comment: Are you getting errors on the server side console? Do you have 2FA setup on your personal account?

Comment: port 465 is for smtps, not smtp, but I'm not sure that matters

Comment: I have also tried port 587 -- that didn't work, and no, I don't have 2FA set up on my gmail account.

Comment: what do you see in the console when trying to send an email. if you run this locally without MAIL_URL set you should the email contents sent. do you not get any kind of error when using gmail for MAIL_URL?

Comment: I occasionally get this error --  WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/387/wlar3fio/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension. -- but when I refresh and try to send the form again it goes away. I don't see anything other than that in the console when I try to set an email.